# If number is less than zero and a negative number hide it jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having the toughest time writing in the function to hide numbers that are equal to or less than zero.  Here is the function I want to write it in at:

```
function isItANumber() {
var increased = parseInt($("#increasedRevenueValue"));

if(isNaN(increased)) {
    $("#increasedRevenueValue").hide();
}

}
```

Any thoughts?  Should I use `OR`?

EDIT:  Here is the fiddle of my code http://jsfiddle.net/YVcj7/

Comment: What type of element has ID `increasedRevenueValue`?

Comment: I think it should be $("#increasedRevenueValue").val() if it is an input element or $("#increasedRevenueValue").text() if it is span/div/any html grouping element.

Comment: The condition isNaN.. needs to be extended as this only takes care of non-numeric values

Comment: This community is also about thoroughly researched and properly written questions.

Comment: I would say I described what I am after pretty thoroughly.  There is even a fiddle to go with it.

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple `<= 0` work?

Comment: @Sparky672 It did work, but you must not have looked at the fiddle.  That was part of the answer but not the whole solution.

Comment: @SethenMaleno The fiddle should support your question, not contain key/crucial pieces to it.  All critical code should be pasted here.

Comment: @XyanEwing That's a more useful answer to the downvotes I am getting.

Comment: @SethenMaleno Haha, that's what I'm here for.  I can't speak for the downvoters, but the reason for my comment is that if jsfiddle is down (godforbid), we'll still need a way to look at/access your code to help you.

Comment: @XyanEwing Makes sense.  I appreciate the comment.  I am open to criticism, but receiving down votes with no reason given is frustrating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following, Im taking a guess at what element your using.

```
function isItANumber() {
    var increased = parseInt($("#increasedRevenueValue").text());

    if(isNaN(increased) || increased <= 0) {
        $("#increasedRevenueValue").hide();
    }
}
isItANumber();
​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/uFAwC/)**

And pure js.. because do we really *need* jQuery for this?

```
function isItANumber(el) {
    var increased = parseInt(el.innerText);

    if(isNaN(increased) || increased <= 0) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
var element = document.getElementById("increasedRevenueValue");
isItANumber(element);
```

**[pure js demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/uFAwC/2/)**
​

Comment: Here is a fiddle of what I am doing maybe you can shed some light in this context: http://jsfiddle.net/YVcj7/

Comment: @SethenMaleno The #increasedRevenueValue is an input field.. You should use .val() to get the value of the input field.

Comment: For some reason, every time I try to find the value and write and if statement for it being less than 0, it's not working out.

Comment: @SethenMaleno http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/YVcj7/1/ in the last function where you do the checkbox click event move `isItANumber()` to the bottom. You were checking the old value before you updated the new value. Also I changed `text()` to `val()`

Comment: @Loktar That was it, bravo.  I guess I still don't really understand the logic behind this.  I get that it was checking the old value, but why did we have to put val in there?

Comment: `val` refers to an input elements data. `text` is used for divs/spans/etc.

Comment: @Loktar I get that, I am just wondering why we have to `parseInt()` that value?

Comment: @SethenMaleno basically just to turn it into a number, otherwise it will be a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
if(isNaN(increased) || increased <= 0){
    $("#increasedRevenueValue").hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can parseInt a jQuery object. I would try `parseInt($("#increasedRevenueValue").text());` or `parseInt($("#increasedRevenueValue").val());` depending on what `#increasedRevenueValue` is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function is doing a bit of double duty (getting the value of a field, checking if it is a number, etc.).

First, I would recommend checking that the value is numeric. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric) has a very good `isNumeric function` that you can leverage.

In that case, you just need to do the following:

```
function isItANumber(value) {
    var value = $("#increasedRevenueValue").val() || $("#increasedRevenueValue").text() //get the value if this is an input field, or fallback on the text otherwise.
    var isNumber = isNumeric(value);
    var isNegative = value < 0;

    if (isNumber && isNegative) {
        $("#increasedRevenueValue").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As people have mentioned, if the element is a input field, your 'increased' should be:

```
var increased = parseInt($("#increasedRevenueValue").val(), 10);
```

If its a div/span/paragraph or something along those lines it should be.

```
var increased = parseInt($("#increasedRevenueValue").text(), 10);
```

Then simply do an if loop.

```
if(increased =< 0) {
    $("#increasedRevenueValue").hide();
}
```

Depending on how your use of this function is you might need to consider if $("#increasedRevenueValue").val() is a empty value, paresint will make it into 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that `$("#increasedRevenueValue")` is an input element,

```
function isItANumber() {
   //change it to $("#increasedRevenueValue").text() if it is div/span
   var increased = parseInt($("#increasedRevenueValue").val(), 10);

   if(isNaN(increased) || increased <= 0) {
       $("#increasedRevenueValue").hide();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/6J7xz/